# Why do my camera's specs give a 120 degree angle of view when I calculate it should be much narrower than that?

Tags: field-of-view, cmos-image-sensor, camera

I have a camera with these specs
Image sensor = 1/4' OV CMOS Sensor
Image Resolution: 1280*1024,640*480,320*240,160*120
Focal Length: 2.8mm
Angle of view: 120

Since it's a 1/4 CMOS i got the width and heigth from here: http://www.photoreview.com.au/tips/buying/unravelling-sensor-sizes
I calculated the horizontal and vertical angle of view and they give me 
65 and 51 respectively. 
[image: Equation]
Then why does it say in the specs that the angle of view is 120? Am I doing something wrong? Help Please.

Comment: Is the sensor possibly not a 3:2 aspect ratio, which would change the assumption about the length of the diagonal?

Comment: I honestly don't know since that's the only information I got.

Answer (score 3):

The angle is usually specified for the diagonal, which gives us 77°.
This is still less than 120° which means the lens is not rectilinear.

Most likely a barrel [distortion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distortion_(optics)), common in [fisheye](https://wiki.panotools.org/Fisheye_Projection) lens - they need a different formula for the angle/focal length calculation.

[image: barrel distortion]